# Reversing and querying the colors of points in an interval

Tags: data-structures

**NOTE: This is a question from a homework for an algorithms course. I am not looking for the solution to it, but possibly some direction on my current approach.**

Here is the question:

> For the interval [0, 1], each point can be colored either white or black. Initially,
>       all of the points are colored white.
>
> Suggest a data structure that supports the following:
>
> Reverse(x, y): Reverse the color of each point between x and y. A point that was black
>       becomes white, and vice versa. The color of other points are not effected.
>
> Report(x): Report the color of x.
>
> The operations should both work in O(log(n)) time, where n is the number of reverse 
>       operations. Do not use more than O(n) space.

Comment: This has been [crossposted](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/232317/suggest-a-data-structure-that-supports-reverse-for-intervals) to P.SE.  [Please don't do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: I was not sure which one was more relevant. I removed the other one.

Comment: @I'd actualy contend that P.SE is probably the better place for this as it falls more into the [algorithm and data structure concepts](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which is the first bullet point of what is on topic for P.SE.

Comment: @MichaelT: Not sure about that. We have seen lots of these questions and answered them here on SO as well. The help center says "questions about software algorithms" are okay. Maybe CS.SE would also be a good fit though.

Comment: My post was downvoted, but I insist for you to take a look at Segment Trees. For the kind of query you're trying (point queries), they're optimal.

Comment: @JuanLopes: It depends. If OP can process the queries "offline", segment trees can be used because you can assign an integral order to the real-valued query borders. For the online case a classical segtree doesn't help, because it is static

Comment: @JuanLopes: Basically a segtree is just a binary search tree, there's nothing special about it. augurar uses the exact same idea in his answer, only by using a self-balancing binary search tree we can get fully dynamic insertion and deleteion.

Comment: Well presented question by the way, @user1661781

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a self-balancing search tree of intervals is a good one.  However, you can save a lot of work by being a bit "lazy".  If an entire subtree needs to be reversed, just set a flag at the root of the subtree.  Later, when traversing that node, you can propagate the flag down the tree.

Also note that adding an interval should only require splitting at most 2 existing intervals, so the tree as at most O(n) nodes, where n is the number of reverse operations performed.

As an example, suppose we have the following tree:
[image: Interval tree example]

Now we are asked to reverse (.1, .9).  This affects every leaf node in tree, but we can get away with visiting at most 2d nodes, where d is the depth of the tree.  In the following diagram, we have performed the reversal.  Border colors indicate what happened:

- Blue - visited
- Cyan - subdivided
- Green - created
- Red - marked for reversal
- Magenta - actually reversed

[image: Reverse example]

Now, suppose we are asked to report the color of 3.5.  We traverse the tree, propagating the reversal flag as we go.
[image: Report example]

As you can see, both operations can be done in O(d), where d is the depth of the tree.  If you keep the tree balanced, this will be O(log(n)).

Comment: I have thought of that before, but I am not confident in it working in the case of overlapping intervals. If I insert (0, 1, W) to begin, and then reverse (.3, .7), it should insert (.3, .7, B). What happens to the (0, 1, W) node?

Comment: @user1661781 In your example, we perform two splits.  First split (0,1) into e.g. (0, .3) and (.3, 1).  Then split (.3, 1) into (.3, .7) and (.7, 1).

Comment: I edited the other one before you responded. Basically, what happens for overlapping intervals? ins(0, 1, W), ins(.3, .7, B). Then you do reverse(.2, .9), which needs three changes: (.3, .7, W), (.2, .3, W) and (.7, .9, B). What if there are many overlapping intervals?

Comment: @user1661781  More generally, in the worst case we split the intervals containing either endpoint of the new interval, and reverse any intervals completely contained within the new interval without splitting.

Comment: @user1661781  In this second case, we split (0, .3) and (.7, 1), and mark (.3, .7) for reversal.  In general we may have to mark up to 2d nodes, where d is the depth of the tree.  However, this is still O(log(n)) if the tree is balanced.

Comment: @user1661781  I'll add a diagram, but it'll take me a little while.

Comment: A diagram might help. You have (0, 0.3, W) and (0.3, 0.7, B). When you do reverse(0.2, 0.9), it must split (0, 0.3, W) into (0, 0.2, W) and (0.2, 0.3, B). Then it must mark (0.3, 0.7, B) for reversal, and then it must also insert (0.7, 0.9, B). It seems like a lot of work for one reversal; if there were 100 nodes, and a reverse overlapped many, it seems like it might get ugly fast.

Comment: If I reverse, [0.01, 1], [0.02, 1] ... [0.99, 1], Wouldn't I end with 100 unbalanced nodes. In this case, the queries wouldn't be O(n)?

Comment: @JuanLopes The assumption is that you are using a self-balancing BST of some kind.

Comment: I still don't think this is the best answer. You would have to implement a custom BST (in order to change intermediary nodes in the balancing process). Still think it's easier to use a Segment Tree which is already a BST (with rigid balancing invariants), it's easier to implement and is specially created for this kind of operations (range update, point query). But if the you prefer an adhoc data structure...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make the diagrams, they helped a lot. Just one quick question: Imagine that reverse(0, 1) was called. This would set the root as marked for reversal. You wouldn't ever actually reverse any node below this, right? It would be way too much work. You would just keep track, on your traversal, of how many True reversed marks you saw. If it is even, then you can trust the color. If it is odd, you cannot. Is this a reasonable assuption?

Comment: @user1661781 When you visit a node marked for reversal, you update its children and remove the mark on that node.  So by the time you reach a child node, its color has been updated to the correct value (as in the last diagram).

Comment: That seems like it would slow the algorithm down unnecessarily. With the example of marking the whole thing as reversed, you would need to actually visit every element.

Comment: @user1661781 No, you just update the _immediate_ children, so it only costs O(1) per node visited.

Comment: Is there a reason why that would work better than counting the number of reversals? EDIT: Nevermind. I think I see why.

Comment: @user1661781  It simplifies whatever operation you're doing to balance the tree, but you might be able to make it work either way.

Comment: Great visualization! Minor nitpick though: It's not really an interval tree anymore if you store disjoint intervals ;) It's basically a binary search tree of border points. Maybe that's even a useful way to think about it instead. Definitely the correct idea though

Comment: Well no, it makes sense to present it this way, and the node annotations with intervals are useful. It's just that you don't need any interval tree features :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [Segment Tree](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor&module=Static#Segment_Trees). You only have to be sure to divide segments in half, to ensure each update create at most O(bits(n)) nodes.

You cannot prove you used O(n) space, but it is O(b) for a b bits input. If the number of bits of "y" is constant, then O(n) it is.

---

Just a little update example:

Initially you would have only one node [0, 1] colored white.

```
[0.0, 1.0, W]
```

Suppose you reverse [0.25, 0.75], you would split the node [0, 1] into:

```
             -------------[0.0, 1.0, ?]----------
            /                                    \
       [0.0, 0.5, ?]                       [0.5, 1.0, ?]
       /           \                       /           \
[0.0, 0.25, W] [0.25, 0.5, B]     [0.5, 0.75, B]   [0.75, 1.0, W]
```

Comment: -1 This doesn't work, because it may require arbitrary depth to represent a single reversed interval.

Comment: @augurar Only if you are dealing with infinite precision floats, which isn't pratically true.

Comment: This is an algorithms question, which generally means we set aside questions of precision.  Otherwise, we could just create a giant array with every representable float value, and claim it takes O(1) space and time for every operation.

Comment: You argument is inconsistent with itself. If we assume each float in the input can have infinite precision, every algorithm is linear, since even if it takes infinite time (or space) it'll be proportional to the input.

Comment: Also, even with arbitrary precision numbers, the number of nodes won't be limitless, it will be bounded by the number of bits in the input.